# How to display data api variable type int in Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, http-post

Can someone help me how to display data from api with variable type integer in flutter? This is my code from screen_api.dart and use method http.post.

```
      void triggerApi() async {
        final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
            body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
              "AutoScalingGroupName": "ASG-api",
              "MinSize": "1",
              "MaxSize": "20",
              "DesiredCapacity": "1",
            }));
    
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          // OK
          final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
          final _info = Info.fromJson(body["result"]);
          setState(() {
            info = _info;
          });
          print(_info.autoScalingName);
          print(_info.minSize);
          print(_info.maxSize);
          print(_info.desiredCapacity);
        }
      }
```

This is for ui and display the data.

```
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('ASG - API'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Text(info != null ? info.autoScalingName : "Loading..."),
            ));
      }
    }
```

This is my models call info.dart

```
    class Info {
      Info(
          {this.autoScalingName, this.minSize, this.maxSize, this.desiredCapacity});
    
      final String autoScalingName;
      final int minSize;
      final int maxSize;
      final int desiredCapacity;
    
      factory Info.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> info) {
        return Info(
          autoScalingName: info["AutoScalingGroupName"],
          minSize: info["MinSize"],
          maxSize: info["MaxSize"],
          desiredCapacity: info["DesiredCapacity"],
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: What you want to display from your model class?

Comment: You can display int using simply toString() method. like- info. desiredCapacity.toString()